# rails: change a relationship to be polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's take a slightly more complex case of the example of polymorphic relationships as seen in [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) (2.9)
Suppose that initially, only a `Product` can have an `Image`; We would have something like this-

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  # nothing yet
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures
end
```

After a while, we want to add the ability for an `Employee` to have an image also;
What kind of migrations do I need to run to make sure that the existing 
Products' images are preserved and the relationship is now polymorphic, like so-

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

Comment: You just need to add two columns `imageable_id and imageable_type` and run command `Picture.all.each do |picture| picture.imageable_type = 'Product'; picture.imageable_id = picture.product_id; picture.save end` You can write this in your migration itself.

Comment: After that you can run migration to remove `product_id` column from `Pictures` table

Comment: @PardeepDhingra I saw you posted this as an answer yesterday, but it's gone today; could you post that again, as it seems a good answer which I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class AddImageableIdAndTypeToPictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :pictures, :imageable_type, :string
    add_column :pictures, :imageable_id, :integer

    Picture.all.each do |picture| 
      picture.imageable_type = 'Product'
      picture.imageable_id = picture.product_id
      picture.save
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write migration like this:

```
remove_foreign_key  :pictures, :products
add_column :pictures, :imageable_type, :string
rename_column :pictures, :product_id, :imageable_id


Picture.update_all(imageable_type: "Product")
```